# select an attribute in mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just start to learn about phpMyAdmin and mysql. here's a question: I want to select something in my "student" table and it echo the result. but as I checked it returns 0 row for the search. but I have it in my database.
here is my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $params="@name varchar(30)";
    $paramslist="@name='$name%";

    $sql = "SELECT  name,address,city,birthday FROM student WHERE NAME=@NAME";

    $dbsql = "EXEC sp_executesql
      N'$sql',
      N'$params',
      $paramslist";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    ECHO $result->num_rows;
```

I don't know what is the problem. thank you for helping.

Comment: This is a very strange way to execute your query. Why are you using a procedure when [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) do this all much more easily? I think despite going through all this trouble you still have a SQL injection bug since `$name` is not properly escaped.

Comment: aren't parameters case sensitive? You are using  `name` and `NAME`

Comment: Why not stick to the methods described in (modern) textbooks and tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT  name,address,city,birthday FROM student WHERE name=".$name;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what works for me with prepared statement

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$name='Veshraj Joshi';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  name,address,city,birthday FROM student WHERE NAME=?");

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

/* now you can fetch the results into an array */
while ($student = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // use your $student array as you would with any other fetch
    echo $student['address'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses prepared statements. You should always use prepared statements when including user input to safeguard for SQL Injection attacks.

Every time `fetch()` executes, the results are bound to the variables specified by `bind_result()`

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$query = "SELECT name,address,city,birthday FROM student WHERE name=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$searchTerm = "%$name%";
$stmt->bind_param('s', $searchTerm);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($resultName, $resultAddress, $resultCity, $resultBirthday);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $resultName . " " . $resultAddress . " " . $resultCity . "<br/>";
}
```